Как сделать что бы vscode показывал все методы стороних класов?
Как сделать что бы vscode показывал все методы стороних класов в python так как это делает pycharm, тоесть когда я установил какой-то модуль в python, в коде pycharm когда я обращаюсь через точку к названию класса перечесляет все методы, вот vscode почему-то так не делает, как это возможно решить?

Стандартный плагин для python это делает. Но нужно выбрать внизу интерпретатор, куда вы пакет устанавливали.
